# How to Authenticate GKE Cluster on Kubernetes API Server using its Java client library

Tags: java, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I am retrieving a list of Clusters from GKE using **GKE Rest API**. Next, I need to retrieve containers information from **Kubernetes API Server** for a particular GKE cluster. There are two authentication methods known to me which can be used to authenticate a cluster with Kubernetes API. First One is Basic Authentication and the second one is Authentication using client certificate and client key. I have found out [Here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/api-server-authentication#legacy-auth) that both of these approaches are no more recommended.

My question is that what other authentication method I can use to authenticate my GKE cluster with Kubernetes API using its Java client library.

Answer (score 1):

The java client should be able to find the pod's service account and authenticate itself within a cluster, and use a kubeconfig file to authenticate when outside cluster.  The default location to look for a kubeconfig file is [`HOME/.kube/config`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/util/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/util/KubeConfig.java#L48-L50)

When outside the cluster, the [`gcloud container clusters get-credentials ...`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials) command will create a kubeconfig file with proper helper configuration to authenticate.  Presumably there is a java way to set up a kubeconfig file without running gcloud from a shell in the [google-cloud-container](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-container/latest/) library.